# I am generating a series of numbers delimited with space but I want to remove the space at end

Tags: java, for-loop, trim

I am generating the series of numbers using for loop, delimited with space but I want to remove trailing space at last. Unable to use trim() for the output.

```
 import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int str = s.nextInt();

    for(int i=1; i<=str; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d", i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    }
}
```

1 2 3 4 5(space here)

but I want output without the space after 5.

Comment: Could you please tell us **why** you are *unable to use `trim()` for the output? What type does your series of numbers have? Is it a `String`? You should really post the code that produces the series here.

Comment: Share some code. Otherwire we're not able to help.

Comment: See the code now. Why don't you just not print the last space then?

Comment: use a stringbuilder if you are building strings inside a loop, you can also just remove the last character when you are getting the value of your stringbuilder, and then log the value, don't just push everything to sys/out/print because then you can't interact with the value

Comment: Thats what I want to know how to remove it? @M. Prokhorov

Comment: @ShantanuUdasi, you don't "remove" it. You *don't print it*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an if test inside the for-loop like this

```
if (i == str) {
    System.out.printf("%d", i); 
} else {
    System.out.printf("%d", i); 
    System.out.print(" "); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;
for(i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
  System.out.print(i + " ");
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you want is to print a space behind every number, except for the last number. You should have this conditional logic in your code somewhere. Like,

```
if (i < str)
    System.out.print(" ");
```

Note: it's very confusing to call a variable `str` if it contains a number; everyone will assume that it's a String instead of a number. You could change code to something like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
        if (i < n)
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```